# Get JSON data based on the item i clicked ionic 2

Tags: javascript, json, ionic2

Hi I want to get the JSON data base only on the item I clicked, when I clicked on the item I dont get any JSON data instead it says its'undefined' in the console. Hope you can help me guys. Here is my code:

```
Featured.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { TestProviderPage } from '../testprovider/testprovider';
import { ProductPage } from '../product/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-featured',
  templateUrl: 'featured.html',
  providers: [TestProviderPage]
})
export class FeaturedPage {
  products: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public testProvider: TestProviderPage) {
    this.loadItems();
  }

  goToProductPage(item){
    this.navCtrl.push(ProductPage, { item: item });
  }

  loadItems(){
    this.testProvider.loadpatrick().then(data => {
    this.products = data;
    console.log(this.products);
    });
  }

}



product.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MorePage } from '../more/more';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-product',
  templateUrl: 'product.html'
})
export class ProductPage {
  item: any;
  tabBarElement: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    this.item = this.navParams.get('product');
    console.log(this.item);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your FeaturePage, you pass parameter **item** to ProductPage. So you just need to retrieve the same parameter.

**FeaturePage.ts**

```
 this.navCtrl.push(ProductPage, { item: item })
```

**Product Page.ts**

```
this.navParams.get('item')
```